# What RSpec hook shall be used to perform clean up task after all tests are finished?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, rspec2

I have this situation in my project - I have a Singleton class representing browser used during the test:

```
class Browser
  include Singleton
  def initialize
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
  end

  def goto url
    @browser.goto url
  end

  def close
    @browser.close
  end
end
```

With this rakefile I wanted to make sure browser gets closed when the tests are finished:

```
desc "default test task"
task :test_all do
  Rake::Task[:all_rspec_tests].invoke
  Rake::Task[:close_browser].invoke
end

desc "runs all rspec tests"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:all_rspec_tests) do |t|
  # run all rspec tests according to pattern for filename
  # tests make use of Singleton class representing browser
end

desc "closes browser used during tests"
task :close_browser do
  Browser.instance.close
end
```

But this doesnt work as expected - RSpec runner instantiates it's own singleton object instance which the close_browser task does not see. So when the close_browser task gets scheduled another browser instance is instantiated and closed right away but the one used during the test remains open. How can I achieve that after all RSpec tests have ran the  browser gets closed?? I guess this must be done with some configuration of the RSpec global hooks?? Would someone point me to an example of such hooks? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to do these things in Rake tasks.  If you just want one browser instance to start at the beginning and persist for all your tests, you can do that in `spec/spec_helper.rb` using a `before :suite` hook.  Something like:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # (other RSpec config)

  config.before(:suite) do
    Browser.initialize # or whatever
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    Browser.close
  end

end
```

This will launch the browser once at the beginning and close it at the end.  It's more likely that you'll want to use before and after hooks only for certain test files, or collections of tests.  Start with the [RSpec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks!).

You might want to consider using [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) instead of Watir; it integrates well with RSpec and you won't have to do this stuff manually.  There's also [watir-rspec](https://github.com/watir/watir-rspec), but I've never used it myself.  This is a solved problem, in any case.  It'll be easier to find something to help you than to set this up on your own.

Comment: Thank you Jim, that solved it! In case others find this usefull, here is a short note - you have to add this line to your rspec tests: `require 'spec_helper'`